# The grid in DataGridSkin is bigger than the dataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, skin

I make a Datagrid, give it columns and so much data that it needs to scroll, and the dataitems are strings so wide that it needs to scroll horizontally as well. I also give it a click listener method.

The problem is that if i click under the datagrid, it still executes the click method. I check the target in the event in the click method, and it says that its "grid" (the Grid in DataGridSkin)

Basically, the "grid" from the skin gets as wide (horizontally and vertically) as there is data even though all the props which show height and width say that it has normal height and width.

The problem is that "grid" intercepts all mouse events making all buttons under the dataGrid useless.

I tried setting maxHeight/Width on the grid, but it does not help.

Is this a error in Spark or what?

EDIT: I just realized that the problem is a bit more specific.

In the main app.mxml we have a huge viewstack and under it a bar with buttons. The navigatorContents of the viewStack are all the different views of my app and changing a view is simply changing the current selectedItem of the viewStack.

Now, the problematic datagrid does not affect any components from the view it is in (but still send a click event if you click directly under it in empty space), but it intercepts all mouseEvents for the buttons in the bar in the main app.mxml.

This is how it looks like: (not the exact code, because its really big)

```
<s:BorderContainer  borderVisible="false" backgroundAlpha="0.5" bottom="0"  visible="{mainViewStack.selectedIndex > 0}" width="100%">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle" paddingLeft="40" paddingRight="40" paddingBottom="0">
        </s:HorizontalLayout>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Label right="60" fontSize="25" color="white" text="some text"/>
    <s:Label right="60" fontSize="12" paddingTop="3" color="white" id="lblVersion"/>
    <s:Spacer width="100%" />

    <s:Image id="img_Back" buttonMode="true" click="img_back_clickHandler(event)" 
             source="@Embed(source='assets/images/undo.png')" toolTip="zurück"/>
    <s:Image id="img_settings" buttonMode="true"
             source="@Embed(source='/assets/images/gears.png')" toolTip="Einstellungen" />
    <s:Image id="img_logout" buttonMode="true" click="img_logout_clickHandler(event)" 
             source="@Embed(source='assets/images/window_key.png')" toolTip="ausloggen"/>
    <s:Image id="img_newWindow" buttonMode="true" click="img_newWindow_clickHandler(event)" 
             source="@Embed(source='assets/images/window_key.png')" toolTip="Neues Fenster"/>

</s:BorderContainer>

<mx:ViewStack id="mainViewStack" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="60" selectedIndex="0" change="mainViewStack_changeHandler(event)" >
    <s:NavigatorContent label="someView" backgroundColor="#707572">
        <someView id="someView"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>

    <s:NavigatorContent label="someView" backgroundColor="#707572">
        <someView id="someView"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>

    <s:NavigatorContent label="someView" backgroundColor="#707572">
        <someView id="someView"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

If any of those views have a datagrid which does stuff like i mentioned above, then it will intercept any mouseEvents for the buttons in the borderContainer.

```
<s:DataGrid id="tableList" width="200" height="100%" doubleClickEnabled="true" doubleClick="createSelectStatement(event)"  >
            <s:columns>
                <s:ArrayList>
                    <s:GridColumn labelFunction="tableLabelFunction" headerText="Tables"/>
                </s:ArrayList>
            </s:columns>
        </s:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Show your code.  Without that, no one is going to be able to help.  It doesn't sound like a problem with the spark component.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i just found a solution for my problem, you simply give the borderContainer depth="2" and the viewStack depth="1" and the datagrid wont intercept the mouseevents for the borderContainer, buts its still wierd, why did i have to do that in the first place?

I'm telling you guys, the dataGrid is bugged, try it yourself, just make a datagrid, give it some columns, so much data it has to scroll and a click event. Click under the datagrid (into the background) and it will still execute the click event.